# Finding the probability that I hit a certain state before another state

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I am given the following transition matrix.$$P =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{3}{4} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{6} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{2}{3} & 0 & 0 &\frac{1}{3}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 & \frac{5}{6}\\
0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2}
\end{pmatrix}.$$

How do I find the probability that if I start in state 4, I hit state 1 before 7? And also given that if I start in state 2, I hit 1 before 7?
In mathematical notation, how do I find the following?

1. $\mathbb{P}_4(H^1 \lt H^7)$
2. $\mathbb{P}_2(H^1 \lt H^7)$

I am really new to Markov Chains and it would be really helpful if anyone could help me with this. I tried drawing the Markov Chain and if state 7 is self absorbing, it is impossible to go to 1 from 4.

Comment: The standard approach to solving these kinds of problems is to define $p_k=\mathbb{P}(E|X_0=k)$ where $k\in \{1,\dots,7\}$ and $E$ is the event of hitting state $1$ before $7$. Using recursion with the total law of probability you can derive a system of equations to solve for $p_k$. Have you tried this? I'm getting $p_4=0$ (as you found) and $p_2=1/11$.

Comment: @MatthewH. Hi, do you mind showing me how you got those values? I'm still struggling...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the given transition probability matrix :
$$P = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1/2 &1/2  &0 & 0&  0&0& \\ 
0 & 0 &1/4  &3/4 & 0&  0&0& \\
1/3 & 1/3 &0  &1/3 & 0&  0&0& \\
0 & 0 &0  &1/6 & 2/3&  1/6&0& \\
0 & 0 &0  &2/3 & 0&  0&1/3& \\
0 & 0 &0  &1/6 & 0&  0&5/6& \\
0 & 1/2 &0  &0 & 0&  0&1/2& \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$

First observe that the chain has one communication class because all the states communicate to each other so the chain is irreducible.

Both questions can be answered if we use the Boundary Value Approach for first hitting probabilities.
Setting $A = \{1\}$ ,$B = \{7\}$

The probability of first hitting the state 1 before hitting the state 7 given that the chain is in state 4 is :

$$\Phi_{A,B}(4) = \mathbb{P}_{4}[T_{1}<T_{7} \mid X_{0} = 4 ]$$

Now the BVP problem can be written:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{lr}
Lh(x)=0,x \notin A,B\\
h(x)=1, x \in A\\
h(x)=0, x\in B
\end{array}\right\}$$

\begin{align*}
    x= 2 : h(2) &= \frac{1}{4} h(3)+ \frac{3}{4}h(4) -h(2)=0  \\
    x= 3 : h(3) &= \frac{1}{3} \cdot 1 +  \frac{1}{3}h(2)+  \frac{1}{3}h(4)  -h(3)=0 \\
    x= 4 : h(4) &= \frac{1}{6}h(4) + \frac{2}{3}h(5)+ \frac{1}{6}h(6) -h(4)=0 \\
    x= 5 : h(5) &= \frac{2}{3}h(4) + \frac{1}{3}\cdot 0 -h(5)=0 \\
    x= 6 : h(6) &= \frac{1}{6}h(4) + \frac{5}{6}\cdot 0  -h(6)=0
\end{align*}

Which is :

\begin{align*}
    x= 2 : h(2) &= \frac{1}{4} h(3)+ \frac{3}{4}h(4) -h(2)=0  \\
    x= 3 : h(3) &= \frac{1}{3} +  \frac{1}{3}h(2)+  \frac{1}{3}h(4)  -h(3)=0 \\
    x= 4 : h(4) &= \frac{1}{6}h(4) + \frac{2}{3}h(5)+ \frac{1}{6}h(6) -h(4)=0 \\
    x= 5 : h(5) &= \frac{2}{3}h(4)  -h(5)=0 \\
    x= 6 : h(5) &= \frac{1}{6}h(4)  -h(6)=0
\end{align*}

Solving the homogeneous system of  these 5 equations we find that $$h(2) = 1/11, h(3)=4/11,h(4)=0,h(5)=0,h(6)=0$$
So the probability of the chain first hitting state 1 before state 7 given that the chain starts from state 4 is $0$

For the second question we have similarly:

$A = \{1\}$ ,$B = \{7\}$
but now :

$$\Phi_{A,B}(2) = \mathbb{P}_{2}[T_{1}<T_{7} \mid X_{0} = 2 ]$$

but the BV problem is exactly as the previous.So the probability of first hitting state 1 before state 7 given that the chain starts from state 2 is $h(2)=1/11$

Another approach that yields the same results is the linear algebra approach that:

You set the matrix say $Q$ that contains the all the rows and all the columns that don't are $A=1,B=7$

$$Q = \begin{bmatrix}
 0.00 & 0.25 & 0.75 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
    0.33 & 0.00 & 0.33 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
    0.00 & 0.00 & 0.17 & 0.67 & 0.17 \\ 
    0.00 & 0.00 & 0.67 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
    0.00 & 0.00 & 0.17 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$

The matrix $R$ that have the rest:
$$R = \begin{bmatrix}
 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
    0.33 & 0.00 \\ 
    0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
    0.00 & 0.33 \\ 
    0.00 & 0.83 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$

The identity matrix:

$$I = \begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0&0&0 \\ 
 0 & 1&0&0 \\ 
 0 & 0&1&0 \\ 
 0 & 0&0&1 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now if you do the $(I - Q)^{-1} R$
you will get the same results :
$$\begin{bmatrix}
 0.09 & 0.91 \\ 
    0.36 & 0.64 \\ 
    0.00 & 1.00 \\ 
    0.00 & 1.00 \\ 
    0.00 & 1.00 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$