# Probability of reaching a state before another state - Markov

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

From the stochastic matrix

$$P = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1/4 & 3/4 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1/3 & 1/3 & 0 & 1/3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/6 & 2/3 & 1/6 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 2/3 & 0 & 0 & 1/3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/6 & 0 & 0 & 5/6 \\ 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Calculate $\mathbb{P}_4(H^1<H^7)$

I am aware of how to calculate $\mathbb{P}_4(H^1< \infty)$, however unsure on this.

My thinking is that it means the probability starting from state 4, that I 'hit' state 1 before state 7?

Comment: Assuming $H^k$ is the first time to hit $k$, then yes that's correct. The one convention question I have to ask before I can actually answer it is whether in your notation $H^k=0$ if you start at $k$ or not.

Comment: Thanks, we have been working under the assumption that $H_k^k=1$.

Comment: Uh...that's a bit of a weird way of writing it. Is the first time of the process $1$ or $0$? Basically the question here is whether $H^k_k$ is a "hitting" time or a "return" time. It makes sense to define it as a hitting time in this setting, so that $P_1(H_1<H_7)=1$ and $P_7(H^1<H_7)=0$, neither of which are generally true for "return" times.

Comment: Hitting times, sorry. I agree that the notation we have learnt in class is weird - it doesn't match up to any of the textbooks

Comment: I have answered the same question 2 days ago [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4369364/finding-the-probability-that-i-hit-a-certain-state-before-another-state/4369679#4369679)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $u(i)=P_i(H^1<H^7)$, then from the total probability formula based on conditioning on the first step, together with the Markov property and the time homogeneity, you have

$$u(1)=1 \\
u(7)=0 \\
u(i)=\sum_{j \neq i} p_{ij} u(j),i \not \in \{ 1,7 \}.$$

This is a linear system that you can solve.

Comment: thanks for your answer